# xpath - how to find a delete link in a given table row?

Tags: selenium, xpath

Given the HTML below how can I find the delete link?

I've been able to select the row with:

```
//td[contains(text(),'DeleteMe')]/../../tr
```

but I can't seem to find a way to select the delete button.

For example I tried:
 `//td[contains(text(),'DeleteMe')]/../../tr//a[@class='delete_link']` but it did not select the link.

I can't use the ID's 403, 113, 112, etc and I need a script without actual ID's for re-testing purposes.

```
<tr class="odd" id="activity_403">
  <td class="name">DeleteMe</td>
  <td class="direct">false</td>
  <td class="">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/admin/roles/113/edit">Language Therapist</a></li>
      <li><a href="/admin/roles/112/edit">Speech Therapist</a></li>
    </ul>
  </td>
  <td class="">
    <a href="/admin/activities/403" class="member_link view_link">View</a>
    <a href="/admin/activities/403/edit" class="member_link edit_link">Edit</a>
    <a href="/admin/activities/403" class="member_link delete_link" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
//td[contains(text(),'DeleteMe')]/../../tr//a[contains(@class,'delete_link')]
```

Comment: Why doesn't `//a[contains(@class,'delete_link')]` by itself work?  (I'm still learning XPath, not second guessing your answer)

Comment: That too should have worked. Perhaps he has multiple similar links.